# ePDQ Payment by link [PHP]

Tags: php, payment

The user has an email with a link from my organisation.
This link goes direct to my account https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/
i.e. it does not reference my organisation's website first.
This is all on the Test environment not Live (real money).

I am trying to use parameters after the url as html email may sometimes not be allowed by a user.

I've not found example code on how to do this.
I was given some pseudo code originally from EPDQ.

Sample url

```
https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp?
amount=12500&
CURRENCY=PND&
LANGUAGE=en_US&
OrderID=order123_001&
PSPID=XXXXX
SHASIGN=XXXX0C75B23EDBAE523E165176882C19BEACB7E7DEB38955224186BC66C2678FEEA4E4CA2512789001CC7A4E68XXXX3EFD35242BFEFBB7B1D4D7E19CBE80XXXX
```

(SHASIGN  some chars changed to XXXX &PSPID changed to XXXXX for security)

Webpage result

```
<--------start----------> 
Payment confirmation
> 
> Order reference :     order123_001 Total charge :     --- Beneficiary
> :     ---
> 
> An error has occurred; please try again later. If you are the owner or
> the integrator of this website, please log into the Barclaycard back
> office to see the details of the error. 
<--------end--------->
```

I used this code to generate the SHA

```
<?php

//- integration user details - //
$PW ="16char_SHA_code";
$PSPID = "XXXXX";
$OrderID ="order123_001";
$PaymentAmount =12500;
$CurrencyCode ="GBP";


$DigestivePlain =
"AMOUNT=" . $PaymentAmount . $PW .
"CURRENCY=" . $CurrencyCode . $PW .
"LANGUAGE=en_US" . $PW .
"ORDERID=" . $OrderID . $PW .
"PSPID=" . $PSPID . $PW .
"";

$strHashedString_plain = strtoupper(hash('sha512',($DigestivePlain)));
print $strHashedString_plain;
?>
```

I have a working HTML form which goes through my organisation website. It allows the user to enter details and a successful payment is made by EPDQ.

`$DigestivePlain` is based on a EPDQ example and works on my HTML form.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure it's 100% clear...are you trying to use PHP to generate a URL string like the one you've labelled as "sample URL"? If so then it doesn't even come close, I'm not sure what you think hashing has to do with it - have you checked what that `$strHashedString_plain` outputs? It's also unclear what any of it has to do with the use of HTML in emails. Can you describe what's going on a bit more precisely please? Assume that we know nothing whatsoever about your scenario (because we don't), and please don't feel you're patronising us - just tell us clearly and in enough detail.

Comment: Or are you trying to use PHP to _read_ data from that URL, that being one which is used to access your site? I can't work it out from what you've said. Again if so, your code doesn't make any mention of attempting to do that.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your comments. With a few corrections I've now got a basic payments screen working.  Hopefully I can now improve on it.  How about a tag [EPDQ] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PHP is to generate the SHASIGN

```
<?php

    //- integration user details - //
    $PW ="MyShaInPassPhrase";
  $PSPID = "MyPSPID"; 
  $OrderID ="order123_001";
  $PaymentAmount =12500;
  $CurrencyCode ="GBP";


//important to order alphabetically
$DigestivePlain =
"AMOUNT=" . $PaymentAmount . $PW .
"CURRENCY=" . $CurrencyCode . $PW .
"LANGUAGE=en_US" . $PW .
"ORDERID=" . $OrderID . $PW .
"PMLISTTYPE=2". $PW .
"PSPID=" . $PSPID . $PW .
"";


$strHashedString_plain = strtoupper(hash('sha512',($DigestivePlain)));
print $strHashedString_plain;
?>
```

Now the url

PSPID: 5 character PSPID (not XXXXX)
SHASIGN - created by php code above  128 characters (not YYYY...)

https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp
?AMOUNT=12500&CURRENCY=GBP&LANGUAGE=en_US&ORDERID=order123_001&PMLISTTYPE=2&PSPID=XXXXX&
SHASIGN=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY

This took me to the EPDQ Card selection screen and then on to the payments screen and a successfull transaction.